# python: groupby 3 columns according to grouping of first two

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Given this dataframe,

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'a': ['john', 'mary','john','john','mary','john'], 'b': [1,2,3,1,1,2],
     'c': [0.7, 0.3,0.9,0.4,1.0,0.2],'d': [1,0,0,1,0,1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

The following line prints out how many times `df['a']=john` and `df['a']=mary` correspond to `df['b']=1,2,3`

```
print(df.groupby('a')['b'].value_counts())
```

What I want to do now is to print out how many times `df['a']=john` and `df['a']=mary` corresponds to `df['d']=1` or `=0` when `df['b']=1,2,3`.
for instance, when `df['a']=john` and `df['b']=1`, `df['d']` is always equal to 1, and when `df['a']=john` and `df['b']=3`, `df['d']=0` etc...

The following line prints out all zeroes and I am not sure why:

```
print((df['d'])[(df.groupby('a')['b'].value_counts())])
```

Comment: `df.groupby('a')['b'].value_counts()` returns a Series that contains just 2's and 1's. `df['d'][2]` and `df['d'][1]` are both 0. Hence all the zeros.

Comment: `df.groupby(['a','b','c']).size()`

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your code to accommodate multiple columns in `groupby`:

```py
print(df.groupby(['a', 'b'])['d'].value_counts())
# a     b  d
# john  1  1    2
#       2  1    1
#       3  0    1
# mary  1  0    1
#       2  0    1
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do `value_counts`

```
out = df.value_counts(['a','b','d'])
a     b  d
john  1  1    2
      2  1    1
      3  0    1
mary  1  0    1
      2  0    1
dtype: int64
```